# Error while merging dex archives when using map_view with flutter android

Tags: android, dart, android-mapview, flutter, dex

So I had been searching forever for the solution to this and what my possible problem could be. I had narrowed down the source of the issue to the map_view plugin. It kept giving me errors with the dex file merge. I eventually found the following flutter issue report: 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12945

In one of the comments it says to go into the ExternalLibraries>firebase_auth>android>build.gradle and change the dependencies from:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.+'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.+'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.+'
}
```

to:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.+'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.+'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.+'
}
```

and to do that for some other gradle files as well... This solution actually cause my app to break when I had map_view removed.

Later I discovered that the dependencies in map_view build.gradle file looked like the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.4-2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.+'
}
```

I changed it to:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.4-2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.+'
}
```

Now it finally works.

Here is an image of the location of the dependency to change:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJpaV.png)

I hope this helps someone. Also, if there is anyone that could explain why this fixed the issue, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter google\_sign\_in error : Unable to merge dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48060925/flutter-google-sign-in-error-unable-to-merge-dex)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886597/multidex-issue-with-flutter